# Was Harry permanently immune to Voldemort's killing curse after Goblet of Fire?

Tags: harry-potter, voldemort, avada-kedavra

We know that the presence of Lily's sacrifice in Voldemort's blood basically tethers Harry to life, allowing him to return. Does this basically mean that between books 4 and 7, Voldemort had no chance of killing him with Avada Kedavra? Like even had he been Avada Kedavra'd 100 times he would have still gotten the chance to come back? Like an infinite get-out-of-death-free card, unless Voldemort found another way to kill him?

Comment: I think infinite is a stretch considering Harry was talking to a ghost in his head and had a choice between taking the next train or returning to the fight.  My reading of it was that Voldemort had strengthened the link between them.  On the one hand, he could bypass Lily's protection.  On the other, he tethered Harry to him in nearly the same way   Voldemort's unknown horcrux tethered him to Harry.  "Killing" Harry broke the link, and even Voldemort seemed to get some backlash, not that he understood it.

Comment: It was quite out of character for Dumbledore to throw the statue in front of Harry to block the curse instead of finding out.